# Why is the array empty until accessed in a loop?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm just digging into a Laravel application and have come across the following function. This is called as part of the routing process (which is what I'm trying to figure out) and I've come across a strange situation where some kind of magic is happening. When the function is called, the $array contains an array of strings. But when I dump out the array at certain points which can be seen below, it's been totally transformed?

```
/**
 * Return the first element in an array passing a given truth test.
 *
 * @param  array  $array
 * @param  callable|null  $callback
 * @param  mixed  $default
 * @return mixed
 */
public static function first($array, callable $callback = null, $default = null)
{
    if (is_null($callback)) {
        if (empty($array)) {
            return value($default);
        }

        foreach ($array as $item) {
            return $item;
        }
}
```

> Array Is empty here

```
dd($array) // []


    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
```

> Array now contains an object

```
        dd($array);


        if (call_user_func($callback, $value, $key)) {
            return $value;
        }
    }

    return value($default);
}
```

Any advice as to what I should be reading up on would be great!

Thanks

Comment: check what you are thinking array may be an object .

Comment: I don't understand where do you dump the array in your function

Comment: @BaptisteArnaud once before the second foreach and once in the second foreach